# How to restrict your iOS app in China storefront?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I have an app developed using React Native. I am getting a message from Apple Review that "Your app needs to be restricted in China storefront." I have no idea how to do that. Can someone help?

Comment: In App Store Connect, go to "pricing and availability" and remove availability in China.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. I already did that.  When submitted for review only Canada and US were available countries. The reviewer was wrong and rejected the app for no reason.  He never admitted his mistake but simply update the app status from "Rejected" to "Under Review" and approved it today as if nothing was wrong. Sure appreciate all who contribute to this site.

Comment: Glad to hear. The reviewers are only human and probably review hundreds of apps per day. I guess mistakes can happen